# How to bring in data into visual studio in specific form. C#

Tags: c#

I am getting started with C# and numl. On the sample project it seems hard coded to accept data in this form

```
var data = Iris.Load();
```

If I have a json file how can I read it into visual studio so it is of the form below and I can run the project with different data.

```
using numl.Model;

namespace MachineLearning
{
    public class Iris
    {
        [Feature]
        public decimal SepalLength { get; set; }
        [Feature]
        public decimal SepalWidth { get; set; }
        [Feature]
        public decimal PetalLength { get; set; }
        [Feature]
        public decimal PetalWidth { get; set; }
        [StringLabel]
        public string Class { get; set; }

        public static Iris[] Load()
        {
            return new Iris[]
            {
                new Iris { SepalLength = 5.1m, SepalWidth = 3.5m, PetalLength = 1.4m, PetalWidth = 0.2m, Class = "Iris-setosa" },
                new Iris { SepalLength = 4.9m, SepalWidth = 3m, PetalLength = 1.4m, PetalWidth = 0.2m, Class = "Iris-setosa" },
                new Iris { SepalLength = 4.7m, SepalWidth = 3.2m, PetalLength = 1.3m, PetalWidth = 0.2m, Class = "Iris-setosa" },
                .
                .
                .
                new Iris { SepalLength = 6.3m, SepalWidth = 2.5m, PetalLength = 5m, PetalWidth = 1.9m, Class = "Iris-virginica" },
                new Iris { SepalLength = 6.5m, SepalWidth = 3m, PetalLength = 5.2m, PetalWidth = 2m, Class = "Iris-virginica" },
                new Iris { SepalLength = 6.2m, SepalWidth = 3.4m, PetalLength = 5.4m, PetalWidth = 2.3m, Class = "Iris-virginica" },
                new Iris { SepalLength = 5.9m, SepalWidth = 3m, PetalLength = 5.1m, PetalWidth = 1.8m, Class = "Iris-virginica" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: newtonsoft json.net is your friend